# Is it possible to get a default value for my image which has an input field of type 'file' in cakephp when I do an edit?

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I have a lots of images in my website and when I try to do an admin edit for those images, I need to enter the image name each time for all of those images even if I need to just do an edit on one image because it is of type 'file'.Is there any work around to populate the default value for the images of type 'file' into the input field? My code is as follows:

```php
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

                $mainimg = $this->request->data['Product']['image'];
                $img1 = $mainimg['name'];

                if ($mainimg['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
                    move_uploaded_file($mainimg['tmp_name'], APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.$img1);
                }
                 //the uploaded file renamed 
                $this->request->data['Product']['image'] = $img1;
```

This is my admin_view.ctp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
}

reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}

} 
<div class="Products form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product',array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));?>
<legend><?php echo __('Admin Edit Product'); ?></legend>    
    <fieldset>

    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description',array('class'=>'ckeditor'));
         echo $this->Form->label('Product Image');
                 $img=$this->data['Product']['image'];
                 echo $this->Html->image($img,array('id'=>'blah','width'=>'100px'));?><br>
                 <div id="dim"><?php echo "Dimension : 170 &#215; 195px";?> </div>

<input type='file' name="data[Product][image]"  id="image" onchange='readURL(this);' >

        <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'));?>
    </fieldset>

</div>
```

The javascript is for previewing the images selected.I am able to preview the default image with this code but not able to get the name of the image  to edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that each time somebody edited a text,they would have to select the images too through choose file.I found a solution where unless the user required to change the image,the current value would exist even if user didnt  select an image.I just added the following code to my controller

```
$product=$this->Product->read(NULL, $id);
$currentimg= $product['Product']['image'];
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

                $mainimg = $this->request->data['Product']['image'];
                $img1 = $mainimg['name'];

                if ($mainimg['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
                    move_uploaded_file($mainimg['tmp_name'], APP.'webroot'.DS.'img'.DS.$img1);

                 //the uploaded file renamed 
                $this->request->data['Product']['image'] = $img1;
}
 elseif($mainimg['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
                    $this->request->data['Product']['image']=$currentimg;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's super global of $_FILES should give you enough information to automatically name your image based on the filename.

Try adding

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
   pr($_FILES);
   ...
```

to your controller function to see what data is being passed through the $_FILES global and use the name that it provides. It would be something like `$_FILES['image'][0]['name'];`. There are also all kinds of information like the size of the file, dimensions, etc. for you to save to the database.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the image name and save it in the database too .If you see my view file, you will see that it is named as $data['Product']['image'] but my problem is that  it doesn't enter that value from the database  into the file field as a default value when i try to do an edit .

Comment: can you post your form from your view?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.I have posted the form from admin_edit.ctp